# MariaDB won't start, even after reinstalling

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, mariadb

I've been reinstalling, update, upgrade but still didn't solve the problem. Been searching for answer on google but the problem persists.
Here's the output when i ran `systemctl status mariadb.service`:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2017-12-30 03:57:41 UTC; 12s ago
  Process: 13654 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 13637 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=ex
  Process: 13630 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13629 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13654 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140601967003392 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140601967003392 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 171230  3:57:40
Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140602510788800 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140602510788800 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140602510788800 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
Dec 30 03:57:40 virtu mysqld[13654]: 2017-12-30  3:57:40 140602510788800 [ERROR] Aborting
Dec 30 03:57:41 virtu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 30 03:57:41 virtu systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Dec 30 03:57:41 virtu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 30 03:57:41 virtu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

At first i think that because of disk full, but after i clean up log in /var/logs, it's still has the same problem.

I also installed iRedMail in the server, and everytime i try to restart mysql, it always return "Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code."
when i run journalctl -xe, it returns:

```
Dec 30 09:06:54 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: 892ED21A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:54 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/980AE1F723: error writing 892ED21A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu sshd[18592]: Invalid user admin from 82.159.78.242 port 60966
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu sshd[18592]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 89CEB21A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: 89CEB21A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/CB9FE1F645: error writing 89CEB21A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu sshd[18592]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 30 09:06:55 virtu sshd[18592]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=82.159.78.242
Dec 30 09:06:56 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8A4DA21A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:06:56 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:06:56 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: 8A4DA21A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:56 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/137012189C: error writing 8A4DA21A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu sshd[18592]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 82.159.78.242 port 60966 ssh2
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8AD3421A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: 8AD3421A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/C6D361F63D: error writing 8AD3421A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:06:57 virtu sshd[18592]: Connection closed by 82.159.78.242 port 60966 [preauth]
Dec 30 09:06:58 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8B73F21A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:06:58 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:06:58 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: 8B73F21A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:58 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/919EB1F6F3: error writing 8B73F21A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:06:59 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8BFD121A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:06:59 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:06:59 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: 8BFD121A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:06:59 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/0D6711F787: error writing 8BFD121A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu sshd[18594]: Invalid user admin from 82.159.78.242 port 32900
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu sshd[18594]: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8C47321A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: 8C47321A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/9D14C1F6B5: error writing 8C47321A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu sshd[18594]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Dec 30 09:07:00 virtu sshd[18594]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=82.159.78.242
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu CRON[18597]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user sogo by (uid=0)
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu CRON[18598]: (sogo) CMD (/usr/sbin/sogo-tool expire-sessions 30 >/dev/null 2>&1; /usr/sbin/sogo-ealarms-notify >/dev/null 2>&1)
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu CRON[18597]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user sogo
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8CB7621A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: 8CB7621A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:07:01 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/729BD218B7: error writing 8CB7621A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:07:02 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8D3DF21A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:07:02 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:07:02 virtu postfix/cleanup[18577]: warning: 8D3DF21A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:07:02 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/72D5621866: error writing 8D3DF21A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu sshd[18594]: Failed password for invalid user admin from 82.159.78.242 port 32900 ssh2
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu sshd[18594]: Connection closed by 82.159.78.242 port 32900 [preauth]
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8DCF821A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu postfix/cleanup[18579]: warning: 8DCF821A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:07:03 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/578D6219A6: error writing 8DCF821A12: queue file write error
Dec 30 09:07:04 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: 8E51121A12: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec 30 09:07:04 virtu postfix/proxymap[17757]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
Dec 30 09:07:04 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf lookup error for "root@mx.illuminareconsulting.com"
Dec 30 09:07:04 virtu postfix/cleanup[18578]: warning: 8E51121A12: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Dec 30 09:07:04 virtu postfix/pickup[17587]: warning: maildrop/CBA4C218B9: error writing 8E51121A12: queue file write error
```

Kindly appreciate if anybody could help.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MariaDB won't start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413792/mariadb-wont-start)

Comment: Well that was my old question which was moved from stack overflow. I will delete that question. Thanks for reminding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the file  `/var/lib/mysql/tc.log` reboot the system and start maria db again. Also ensure there is enough space in `/var` and `/tmp` if you're using separate partition for them.

I think once your `/var` partition got full and so `mariadb` failed to create `tc.log` file and ended up creating a 0 bit file which is causing the problem.

[This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151183/mariadb-cant-init-tc-log/151828) may be helpful.

Comment: YOU'RE MY SAVIOR! One question, is it safe to delete files in /var/log and /var/temp? Because those two dirs is creating an enermous size of logs until it took all my disk space, especiall /var/log/.

Comment: You shall setup log rotation for log files. This will split log files daily or monthly basis depending on your setup. And then setup a `cornjob` to delete old logs. Otherwise you may manually delete them after some days. No harm in doing so. I don't have a `/vat/temp` directory and don't know about it. However `/tmp` contains some saved cookie etc. Removing them will log out your clients. And some temporary saved details like `yum` update details may gone. But no permanent harm to system.

Comment: Okay then probably i should create a cronjob to automatically delete old logs. Thank you so much for the explanation and solution!

Comment: @RadityaAdiBaskara Take a look at the `logrotate`.

Comment: You save my life.. :D